# Query with parameters in C# (using SQL Server)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a problem with query in C#.

I have this part of code :

```
string query1 = @"
            SELECT TOP @howManyRows * FROM
            (
            SELECT
               PRODUCTCODE_.ID_ AS PRODUCTCODE_ID_,
               PRODUCTCODE_.CATEGORY_ AS CATEGORY_,
               PRODUCTCODE_.DESCRIPTION_ AS DESCRIPTION_,
               PRODUCTCODE_.MANUFACTURER_ AS MANUFACTURER_,
               PRODUCTLINE_.CREATION_DATE_ AS CREATION_DATE_,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PRODUCTCODE_.CATEGORY_) AS ROWNUMBER_,
               TOTALROWS_ = COUNT(*) OVER()
            FROM
               PRODUCTCODE_
            INNER JOIN
               PRODUCTLINE_ ON PRODUCTLINE_.ID_ = PRODUCTCODE_.PRODUCTLINE_ID_        
            ) _tmpList
            WHERE 
               ROWNUMBER_ >= @startingWith
               ORDER BY CATEGORY_
            ";


SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter();
param1.ParameterName = "@howManyRows";
param1.Value = resultPerPage; //`resultPerPage` is an integer function parameter

SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
param2.ParameterName = "@startingWith";
param2.Value = startsWith;  //`startWith` is an integer function parameter

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( query1, connect );
cmd.Parameters.Add( param1 );
cmd.Parameters.Add( param2 );
```

When debug arrived to `SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();` then the exception is thrown:

> Incorrect syntax near @howManyRows ...

Why ? I defined and added `howManyRows` with `Parameters` property.

Where is my mistakes ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your top query syntax from

```
SELECT TOP @howManyRows * FROM
```

to

```
SELECT TOP (@howManyRows) * FROM
```

Comment: Awesome.  Never knew you could do this.

Comment: @Fraz: the `()` is needed to `@startingWith` from WHERE clause ?

Answer (score 3):

Try wrapping the parameter specified next to TOP in parentheses, like so:

```
SELECT TOP (@howManyRows) * FROM
```

Answer (score 3):

You need parenthesis to parametrise TOP

```
SELECT TOP (@howManyRows) * FROM
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
SELECT
           PRODUCTCODE_.ID_ AS PRODUCTCODE_ID_,
           PRODUCTCODE_.CATEGORY_ AS CATEGORY_,
           PRODUCTCODE_.DESCRIPTION_ AS DESCRIPTION_,
           PRODUCTCODE_.MANUFACTURER_ AS MANUFACTURER_,
           PRODUCTLINE_.CREATION_DATE_ AS CREATION_DATE_,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PRODUCTCODE_.CATEGORY_) AS ROWNUMBER_,
           TOTALROWS_ = COUNT(*) OVER()
        FROM
           PRODUCTCODE_
        INNER JOIN
           PRODUCTLINE_ ON PRODUCTLINE_.ID_ = PRODUCTCODE_.PRODUCTLINE_ID_        
        ) _tmpList
        WHERE 
           ROWNUMBER_ between @startingWith and (@startingWith + @howManyRows)
           ORDER BY CATEGORY_
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a couple of parenthesis to make it work.

```
SELECT TOP (@howManyRows) * FROM
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
SELECT TOP (@howManyRows) * FROM
```

**But this really depends on the Database Server you are using. For example, this is only supported from MSSQL Server 2005 upwards**

If this does not work you can do the following...

You can include this into your query string. **But** this can result in Sql Injection if you don't check the value of your variable.

#### Sample

```
int top = 10;
Int32.TryParse(howManyRows.ToString(), out top);

string query1 = "SELECT TOP " + top.ToString() + @" * FROM
(
SELECT
    PRODUCTCODE_.ID_ AS PRODUCTCODE_ID_,
    PRODUCTCODE_.CATEGORY_ AS CATEGORY_,
    PRODUCTCODE_.DESCRIPTION_ AS DESCRIPTION_,
    PRODUCTCODE_.MANUFACTURER_ AS MANUFACTURER_,
    PRODUCTLINE_.CREATION_DATE_ AS CREATION_DATE_,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PRODUCTCODE_.CATEGORY_) AS ROWNUMBER_,
    TOTALROWS_ = COUNT(*) OVER()
FROM
    PRODUCTCODE_
INNER JOIN
    PRODUCTLINE_ ON PRODUCTLINE_.ID_ = PRODUCTCODE_.PRODUCTLINE_ID_        
) _tmpList
WHERE 
    ROWNUMBER_ >= @startingWith
    ORDER BY CATEGORY_
";
```

Comment: Yes, I used that but at every line of SQL syntax (described above) I have to use `" "` and `+` symbol that is very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SELECT TOP(@howManyRows)` syntax